# TSQL, If there are no results then write 'no results' in one of the fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a series of queries in a stored procedure that are connected with UNION. If they all return no values ie. Rowcount = 0 then I want to have the query say 'No Records' in one of the text fields

I have the below after my union, but it acts as two separate queries so get 2 sets of results. I need to have only one, i tried Unioning this onto the end with no luck as i think it doesnt do the count properly as the query isn't finish when it is run as part of the union.

Any help would be great.

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT       NULL AS [Date/Time]
                ,NULL AS [Event ID]
                ,NULL AS [Action Performed By]
                ,NULL AS [Action Performed On]
                ,NULL AS [Action]
                ,'No records balh balh' AS [Entitlement Being Changed]
                ,NULL AS [Description of Change]
                ,NULL AS [Application Name]
                ,NULL AS [Machine Name]
END
```

Comment: use CASE WHEN THEN END in this case

Comment: can you post your whole query?

Comment: Consider inserting your data from the first part into a table variable, if the table variable has no rows insert the "No records" row, then return the table variable.

Comment: Don't do things like this, please... saying 'No Results Found' is a **UI** function _not_ a _database_ function.  You probably especially shouldn't be returning that as part of a stored procedure - actually return the empty table.  This is just wierd, and 'fails' use cases of things like using it for `EXISTS` clauses.  Also, this isn't easily internationalizable.

Comment: to elaborate on what im trying to do, when the query is returned im using SSIS to put it into an .XLS file as a report for a business user. this is an automatic process so when the user receives a blank report I wanted to inform them by having one of the fields say that the was no data. I'm pretty new to this so apologies if im not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply saying "don't do this" isn't particularly helpful.

Assuming that there is no UI and you need the returned dataset to somehow acknowledge the fact that no matching records were found as opposed to simply being blank then you could try using a temporary table.

In your stored procedure select the results of your union query into a temp table. Then check the temporary table for existing records and either return the contents of the temporary table or your default 'none found' record.

Answer (score 3):

While I heartily agree with X-Zero, the following serves as a horrible example:

```
declare @Stuff as table ( Thing varchar(16) )
insert into @Stuff ( Thing ) values ( 'Congress' ), ( 'Progress' ), ( 'Oxymoron' )

declare @SelectNought as Bit = 1 -- Flip me!

; with Aleph as (
  ( select Thing, 0 as Flag
    from @Stuff where Thing like 'C%' and @SelectNought = 0
  union all
  select Thing, 0 as Flag
    from @Stuff where Thing like 'P%' and @SelectNought = 0
  union all
  select Thing, 0 as Flag
    from @Stuff where Thing like 'O%' and @SelectNought = 0 ) ),
Beth as (
  select * from Aleph
  union all
  select 'Nope', 1 )
  select Thing from Beth where Flag = ( case when exists ( select * from Beth where Flag = 0 ) then 0 else 1 end )
```

Let me emphasize: **Don't go here!**

Answer (score 1):

I agree with X-Zero. If there are no results from your database call, let the UI handle what to display to the user. As stated, that is a UI function and is not a best practice for separation of concerns.